# Best way to wait for a chrome.tabs.query callback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension for my own use. I'm querying the current tab's index from an injected script like this:

**[injected script]**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({whatIsMyIndex:1}, function(response){
   var myIndex = response.index;
});
```

**[background script]**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.whatIsMyIndex){
         sendResponse({index: sender.tab.index});
      }
   }
);
```

Now this is all good and fine, but then I need to return the url of the first tab as well:

**[injected script 2]**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({whatIsMyIndex:1}, function(response){
   var myIndex = response.index;
   var url = response.url;
});
```

**[background script 2]**

```
var url;

//this uses sendResponse when the requested values arrive
function respond(sendResponse, index){
   if(typeof(url)!="undefined"){
      sendResponse({index:index, url:url});
   } else {
      setTimeout(respond, 15, sendResponse, index);
   }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.whatIsMyIndex){
         chrome.tabs.query({index:0, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs){
            url=tabs[0].url;
         }
         setTimeout(respond, 15, sendResponse, sender.tab.index);
         return true; //so i can use sendResponse later
      }
   }
);
```

Now, this code works just fine. **My question is, is there any way to accomplish this without the need for setTimeout?** Adding a fixed 15ms delay doesn't seem right.

If only I could get chrome.tabs.query's callback to take my sendResponse() as a parameter...

(Storing sendResponse() in a global variable is not possible, since there will be ~20 tabs doing this at the same time, and all of them need their own responses.)

I don't need any working (or not working) code here, only some ideas/guidelines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call `sendResponse` inside the `chrome.tabs.query` callback, instead of setting the variables:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.whatIsMyIndex){
         chrome.tabs.query({index:0, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs){
            sendResponse({index:sender.tab.index, url:tabs[0].url});
         });
         return true; //so i can use sendResponse later
      }
   }
);
```

Each invocation of the `onMessage` callback function creates a new closure, so the `sendResponse` inside the `tabs.query` callback function will be bound to the right function.

Comment: Awesome, saved hours of trying to figure that one out, but why does the `return true` help make this work?!

Comment: @rsanchez Thank you, I could solve my problem with this too. and I just wonder, why it is not working without 'return true;'?. This was my problem, and I still don't understand how it works. I thought once we return something, the connection between background and popup will be done... please advise,